# What is the command to install azuredevops provider in cdktf?

Tags: terraform, cdktf

What is the command to install azuredevops provider in cdktf ?
Something like  ** npm install @cdktf/provider-azuredevops**

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the [Azure Devops Provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/microsoft/azuredevops/latest/docs) you need to add the provider to your [`cdktf.json`](https://www.terraform.io/cdktf/concepts/providers-and-resources#add-provider-to-cdktf-json) and then run `cdktf get` to generate the bindings.

Answer (score 0):

As of writing (26 June 2022) there doesn't appear to be an npm package like `@cdktf/provider-azuredevops` or similar yet.

The registry entry for the Terraform provider is located here: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/microsoft/azuredevops/latest/docs

The source code can be found here: https://github.com/microsoft/terraform-provider-azuredevops

Here are two possible work arounds until an appropriate npm package for CDKTF becomes available:

1. Have a separate Terraform project and use Terraform proper including the Terraform Provider for Azure DevOps (see links above)
2. Use the Azure DevOps REST API, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1

In case any reader has come across an npm package for CDKTF, please consider adding a new answer to this SO question.